# Unit testing framework/library for C

Tags: open-source, library, software-development, c, software-testing

I'm looking for a unit testing framework or library for C code, with the framework/library itself written in C.

Required features:

- Can be used on Unix-like operating systems, specifically GNU/Linux.
- Can be used on Windows (albeit possibly with WSL or Cygwin or whatever).
- Gratis.
- Libre.
- Non-tiny userbase.
- Does not require you to spell out the names of testcase/test suites twice (i.e. once to define them, then again to use them).
- not-abandoned.

Desired features:

- Works with a C++ compiler.
- Does not require C11 features.
- Supports most of the features of common C++ unit testing libraries like doctest and catch2.
- Actively developed.
- Is built using CMake rather than autotools or hand-written makefile.